# How can I do a substring in a linq query?

Tags: linq, parsing, select

I have a database table with a column name `FILES`.

The data for the `FILES` column looks like this

```
//directory/anotherdirectory/file1.txt

//directory/anotherdirectory/file2.txt

//directory/anotherdirectory/file3.txt
```

I want the linq to create a string like

```
"file1.txt\nfile2.txt\file3.txt"
```

I want to be able to select the column and parse the data at the same time.

The following two ways give errors.

```
string filesNames = string.Join("\n", _repositoryFactory
                .GetRepository<MyResponseEntity>()
                .Entity
                .ByMyId(id).Select(x => {x.FILES = "Just a test"; return    x}).ToArray());
```

I have also tried do a substring with no luck

```
string filesNames = string.Join("\n", _repositoryFactory
                    .GetRepository<MyResponseEntity>()
                    .Entity
                    .ByMyId(id).Select(x => x.FILES.Substring(x.FILES.LastIndexOf('/')+1, 
                                  x.FILES.Length - (x.FILES.LastIndexOf('/')+1)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Instead of Substring, can you use Contains?

Comment: No, I have to strip out the file name, but I do not know what the file name is.

Answer (score 0):

Using Aggregate method.

```
var fileNames = _repositoryFactory
                    .GetRepository<MyResponseEntity>()
                    .Entity
                    .ByMyId(id)
                    .Select(e => e.Substring(e.LastIndexOf('/') + 1))
                    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "\n" + b);
```

Comment: It gave me an error  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @user1854438 Is the following using included: "using System.Linq;"?

Answer (score 0):

```
string filesNames = string.Join("\n", _repositoryFactory.GetRepository<MyResponseEntity>()
                       .Entity.ByMyId(id).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x.FILES)).ToArray());
```